# Mean value theorem for composition/multi-variable function $\frac{f(u, g(u)) - f(v,g(v))}{u-v}$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I would like to apply the mean value theorem for a function $f:\mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$ to write down
$$\frac{f(u, g(u)) - f(v,g(v))}{u-v}$$
where $g: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$.
If I only had $\frac{f(u) - f(v)}{u-v}$, I would apply Lagrange's theorem to write
$$\frac{f(u) - f(v)}{u-v} = \int_0^1 f'(\theta u + (1-\theta)v) d\theta.$$

How can I do the same for the case of  $$\frac{f(u, g(u)) - f(v,g(v))}{u-v}$$

?

How does this generalize if I consider $$\frac{f(u, g(u)) - f(v, g(v))}{u-v}$$ where $u,v:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ are themselves  functions?

Answer (score 1):

$F(x) = f(x,g(x))$ is a a real map taking real values.

You can compute its derivative using the chain rule:

$$F^\prime(t) = f_x^\prime(t, g(t)) +g^\prime(t) f^\prime_y(t,g(t))$$ and then apply Taylor Lagrance theorem

$$\begin{aligned}\frac{F(u) - F(v)}{u-v} &=
\frac{f(u,g(u)) - f(v,g(v))}{u-v}\\
&= \int_0^1 F^\prime(\theta u + (1-\theta)v) \ d\theta\end{aligned}$$

Comment: Thank you. How does this generalize if I consider $\frac{f(u, g(u)) - f(v, g(v))}{u-v}$ where $u,v:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ is itself a function?

Comment: And what do you mean by $f'_y$?

Comment: Please read again the question. The generalization is already done. $f•\prime_y$ is the partial derivative regarding the seconde variable.

Comment: So you mean $$\frac{f(u,g(u)) - f(v,g(v)}{u-v}= \int_0^1 g^\prime(\theta u + (1-\theta)v) \quad \partial_2 f(\theta u + (1-\theta)v,g(\theta u + (1-\theta)v)) \ d\theta$$? If yes, why no derivative with respect to the first variable "$\partial_1$" appears?

Comment: @Jun That’s a typo. Now fixed.